# PHP - dns_get_record - Why is DNS_PTR always returning an empty array?

Tags: php

I am trying to obtain ptr records for a domain.

For some reason when i try to do this using dns_get_record it is constantly coming back as empty.

I did try this originally and got a whole range of results but now its just returning an empty array every time... Could someone suggest the reason behind this behaviour?

```
$result = dns_get_record("webstorm.co.za", DNS_PTR);
print_r($result);
```

outputs :

```
Array()
```

When it would be populated with values?

Any suggestions, advice or feedback would be greatly appreciated as i cannot for the life of my figure out why this is happening now!

Comment: because PTR records are used to map IPs->Hostnames. you're looking up a hostname, not an IP. e.g. you're already at the destination.

Comment: @MarcB Thank you for your input in this as it is always helpful! But I am still quite confused with this one... I am quite sure that i tried this exact domain earlier but received the PTR records on it... I also tried mail.finn.co.za which produced results. Maybe i am simply mistaken but in this case how could i use this function to obtain the PTR records correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**updated**

try

```
$result = dns_get_record("41.78.244.4.in-addr.arpa.", DNS_PTR);
print_r($result);
```

outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [host] => 41.78.244.4.in-addr.arpa
            [class] => IN
            [ttl] => 108002
            [type] => PTR
            [target] => dialup-4.244.78.41.Dial1.StLouis1.Level3.net
        )

)
```

You wont get prt from a domain name. 
You need to run it on a reverse name.

you can get more info in here:
http://www.menandmice.com/knowledgehub/dnsqa/56/

Comment: Outputs Array() when there should be valid PTR records?

Comment: Thank you so much for your input! but where does this "in-addr.arpa" come from?

Comment: from here... http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2317.txt

you are using arpanet after all, arnt you? :P

Comment: Woah you have totally lost me :) I am simply helping out a friend by trying to build him a function to check certain records relating to any specific domain... say for instance we wanted the ptr records on mail.finn.co.za, how would i look that up? I understand how to get the ip, but how do did you find that extra bit? Very confusing!

Comment: on a very lame way to phrase it you could say is that you can't ask a dns what the ip name, you can ask what the ptr, and you do it by using the reverse name of the ip.   so you could say (but not really) that 41.78.244.4.in-addr.arpa is the default NAME of that IP.

Comment: I will read through this very hard and then think about your answer some more... I know that you are correct in what you are telling me but i am battling to understand how this works :) Thank you so much for your input i really do appreciate it!